Cannot import torch
I install torch using conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia  and when i try to import it i see error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Anacondat Path\envs\EnvName\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "Anacondat Path\envs\EnvName\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\c10_cuda.dll" or one of its dependencies.


If you are working on a CPU, activate the conda environment and run:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

If you are running on GPU:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118


The same problem, because i install all the requirements and i change the env to another python versions but still the same problem
